# R not reading even simple CSV files created/converted in Excel

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to do some analytics at work that Excel is not great at. However, none of the CSV files I save from Excel can be read by R. I tried to create CSVs in OpenOffice too with the same result. As a test, I download a CSV from a teaching website:

http://taddylab.com/teaching.html

As a test, I tried opening "pickup.csv" from this site and it was read in fine. However, when I opened the file in Excel and saved it as a new csv and tried to read it again, it doesn't work anymore. This indicates that the problem is somehow related to the csv files that my software is outputting. it's not a problem confined to Excel though cause apparently a csv created in OpenOffice has the same issue.

For the failed reads, I get one error and multiple warning:

```
  Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'simplest.csv'
```

This is what the data looks like in both files, just super simple:

```
 year   miles   price   make
    2008    17638   14995   GMC
    2003    174000  8500    Dodge
    2001    1500    9998    Dodge
    2007    22422   23950   GMC
    2007    34815   19980   GMC
    1997    167000  5000    GMC
    1999    142000  2800    Dodge
    2003    86000   7900    Dodge
    2002    115000  6700    Dodge
```

Any idea what is the problem here? I'm working in a Korean work environment, but as you can see there are no strange markers in the file. However, the icons do look different between my downloaded file and  so I wonder if it is some encoding issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7q1z.jpg

EDIT: Here's the line that fails. It's not very illuminating

```
> > a<-read.csv("pickup.csv")
> > a1<-read.csv("testpickup.csv") Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) :    invalid multibyte string 1 In addition: Warning messages: 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote =
> quote,  :   line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls 2: In
> read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
> incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'testpickup.csv'
```

Pickup.csv is the original file and testpickup.csv is the version I ran through Excel - eg, I opened pickup.csv in Excel, hit save as csv and then named it TestPickup.  Keep in mind, these files have identical content.  To clarify, I can read.csv the files from the taddylab page fine, it's just that the csv files created from my Excel are unreadable with 'read.csv' for some reason.

SOLVED: Apparently, it's encryption getting in the way. Not sure if this will work for every file or every setting, but I copied and pasted the excel data into a text file which ended up as a tab delimited table. Read it in with:

```
   df2<-read.table("samplefile.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

And now I can play around with the data

Comment: you didn't give us the line that fails... but in any case try `fread` from `data.table`, it's faster and guesses a bunch of things

Comment: The snippet you show works for me. Please share enough of the file to reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm using a read.csv, not read.table. I don't think it's the code that's failing, but something about the file output from Excel that i'm not accounting for or is just corrupted.

Comment: Depending on the region of the planet, `csv` files can have column separators other than the comma. In my country Excel uses the semi-colon. To read these files there is `read.csv2`.

Comment: Never (and I say never) open a csv file with a spreadsheet (Excel or OpenOffice) and re-save it. It will change a lot. Open both files (the csv before using excel and one produced by excel) with a text editor and you'll see that something changed (maybe the separator or date format or quotes or anything) in the process.

Comment: Read.csv2 sadly produced no real change. I would love to not use Excel to create the CSV file, but I'm not sure how else to copy and paste data from Excel into a usable format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function read.csv instead, as it use the correct settings for headers and separators which are likely the problem with the more general read.table function. I have just tried it with 1 csv file from the page and it works fine.

Comment: I'm using a read.csv, not read.table. The csvs on the page do work fine for me. It's just that when i produce a csv from excel - Even if it is a CSV created from the original working file, then it can't be read by R

Comment: Take a look at the details when exporting the csv files. Depending on the language setup they sometimes get exported with additional "" or semicolon ; instead of comma. As I do not have one of your excel exported files, I cannot check them.

Comment: Actually, I think the output csv file is encrypted. The output in Notepad requires a password to open. I'm not sure how to get around it with R, but I guess this is something I'll have to consult our IT about.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's encryption getting in the way. Nothing too useful to learn, sorry, just something to look out for if you're in a corporate setting.

EDIT: Not sure if this will work for every file or every setting, but I copied and pasted the excel data into a text file which ended up as a tab delimited table. Read it in with:

```
df2<-read.table("samplefile.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

And now I can play around with the data